# JSON and Highlights on Datepicker

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, datepicker

just a quick question about datepicker and json. I have this code:

```
var dates = {'2013/4/4':'some description' , '2012/6/6':'some other description'}; 

                    function date_propogate() {
                    console.log('in function');
                        $.getJSON('URL OF JSON', function(data) {
                        date_items = data.items;
                        console.log(date_items);
                            $.each(date_items, function(index, date_item) {
                                dates.push(date_item.sdate);
                            });
                        });
                    }

                    $(document).ready(function() {

                    date_propogate();

                    $('#datepicker').datepicker({                
                        beforeShowDay: function(date) {

                        var search = date.getFullYear() + "/" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + (date.getDate());


                        if (dates[search]) {
                                return [true, 'highlight', dates[search] || ''];
                                }

                                return [false, '', ''];
                            }

                        });
                    });
```

The JSON page returns this:

```
{"items":[{"sdate":"2013-02-25","edate":"2013-02-27","cost":"200","id":"1"}]}
```

I have two dates which are static which display fine, but the date which is returned by: date_items.sdate is not loading, I am getting an error saying 'no method: push'.

Am I doing this correctly at all or is there a better way? As I'm assuming I can't do it with just php on the page because the js is loading before  the php right?

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have `dates` declared as an object using `{}`, rather than an array using `[]`. You can't call `.push()` on an object.

Answer (score 0):

dates is an object and an object doesn't have a function called push. Arrays do have these functions.

Anyway, simply do this:

`var dates = ['2013/4/4':'some description' , '2012/6/6':'some other description'];`

Answer (score 0):

Dates is not an array, so you can't push to it.  You would need to define dates as an array

```
var dates = [{'2013/4/4':'some description'} , {'2012/6/6':'some other description'} ]
```

The above creates an array of objects.